# How to integrate Spring Data Neo4j and Mongodb in Grails 2.4.2 Project

Tags: mongodb, grails, spring-data-neo4j

I am creating a Grails Project , I need to integrate Neo4j and Mongodb , For neo4j I use SDN(Spring Data Neo4j) and for MongoDb we use Grails Plugin

```
This is our Dependencies and Plugins 
 dependencies {
            // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes e.g.
            // runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.29'
            // runtime 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.3-1101-jdbc41'
        //  compile 'org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm:3.1.2.RELEASE'
        //  compile 'org.grails:grails-datastore-core:3.1.2.RELEASE'
        //  test 'org.grails:grails-datastore-simple:3.1.2.RELEASE'
            //compile 'org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm:3.1.0.RELEASE'
            //compile 'org.grails:grails-datastore-core:3.1.0.RELEASE'
        //  test 'org.grails:grails-datastore-simple:3.1.0.RELEASE'
          //  test "org.grails:grails-datastore-test-support:1.0-grails-2.4"
            compile 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-neo4j-rest:3.2.0.RELEASE'
            compile 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:1.9.0.RELEASE'
            //compile 'javax.validation:validation-api:1.1.0.Final'



        }

        plugins {
            // plugins for the build system only
            build ":tomcat:7.0.54"
            compile ":mongodb:3.0.2"
            // plugins for the compile step

            compile ":scaffolding:2.1.2"
            compile ':cache:1.1.7'
            compile ":asset-pipeline:1.8.11"

            // plugins needed at runtime but not for compilation
            runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.5.4" // or ":hibernate:3.6.10.16"
            runtime ":database-migration:1.4.0"
            runtime ":jquery:1.11.1"

            // Uncomment these to enable additional asset-pipeline capabilities
            //compile ":sass-asset-pipeline:1.7.4"
            //compile ":less-asset-pipeline:1.7.0"
            //compile ":coffee-asset-pipeline:1.7.0"
            //compile ":handlebars-asset-pipeline:1.3.0.3"
        }
```

Now when we run our Project it shows an error

```
|Running Grails application
        | Error 2014-10-14 11:31:36,385 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoaderListener  - Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'mongoOpenSessionInViewInterceptor': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoDatastore' while setting bean property 'datastore'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoDatastore': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.data.util.ClassTypeInformation.from(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/springframework/data/util/TypeInformation;
        Message: Error creating bean with name 'mongoOpenSessionInViewInterceptor': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoDatastore' while setting bean property 'datastore'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoDatastore': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.data.util.ClassTypeInformation.from(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/springframework/data/util/TypeInformation;
            Line | Method
        ->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
        - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
        |   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
        |    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
        ^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
        Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoDatastore': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.data.util.ClassTypeInformation.from(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/springframework/data/util/TypeInformation;
        ->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
        - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
        |   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
        |    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
        ^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
        Caused by NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.data.util.ClassTypeInformation.from(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/springframework/data/util/TypeInformation;
        ->>  255 | createMongoTemplate in org.grails.datastore.mapping.mongo.MongoDatastore
        - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
        |    221 | afterPropertiesSet in     ''
        |     54 | getObject in org.grails.datastore.gorm.mongo.bean.factory.MongoDatastoreFactoryBean
        |    262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
        |   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
        |    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
        ^    745 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
        Error |
        Forked Grails VM exited with error
```

We try many dependencis they are comment in that BuildConfig.groovy ,But we get the exception every time ,Please suggest us

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem Solved .There is missing of dependency 
Change your BuildConfig.grrovy with this `

```
grails.servlet.version = "3.0" // Change depending on target container compliance (2.5 or 3.0)
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
grails.project.work.dir = "target/work"
grails.project.target.level = 1.6
grails.project.source.level = 1.6
//grails.project.war.file = "target/${appName}-${appVersion}.war"

grails.project.fork = [
    // configure settings for compilation JVM, note that if you alter the Groovy version forked compilation is required
    //  compile: [maxMemory: 256, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],

    // configure settings for the test-app JVM, uses the daemon by default
    test: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],
    // configure settings for the run-app JVM
    run: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
    // configure settings for the run-war JVM
    war: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
    // configure settings for the Console UI JVM
    console: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256]
]

grails.project.dependency.resolver = "maven" // or ivy
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    // inherit Grails' default dependencies
    inherits("global") {
        // specify dependency exclusions here; for example, uncomment this to disable ehcache:
        // excludes 'ehcache'
    }
    log "error" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
    checksums true // Whether to verify checksums on resolve
    legacyResolve false // whether to do a secondary resolve on plugin installation, not advised and here for backwards compatibility

    repositories {
        inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

        grailsPlugins()
        grailsHome()
        mavenLocal()
        grailsCentral()
        mavenCentral()
        // uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable remote dependency resolution from public Maven repositories
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
        //mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
        mavenRepo 'http://m2.neo4j.org/content/repositories/releases/'
    }

    dependencies {
        compile 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb:1.6.0.RELEASE'        
        compile 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-neo4j-rest:3.2.0.RELEASE'
        compile 'javax.validation:validation-api:1.1.0.Final'



    }

    plugins {
        // plugins for the build system only
        build ":tomcat:7.0.54"

    //  compile ":neo4j:2.0.0-M02"
        // plugins for the compile step

        compile ":scaffolding:2.1.2"
        compile ':cache:1.1.7'
        compile ":asset-pipeline:1.8.11"
        compile ":mongodb:3.0.2"
        runtime ":jquery:1.11.1"

    }
}
```

Comment: I am receiving an error regarding to config found neo4j...any thoughts?